# JML: How to specify a requirement of an array with crescent elements?

Tags: java, specifications, jml

I want to do that in JML:

```
//@ requires (\forall int i : array[i] < array[i+1])
void calculatesDistances(int[] array){
 ..
}
```

I couldn't make it work, saw a lot of examples in JML specs, but couldn't find a way how to do it.

So, how can i make it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to "guard" against nonsense array values using implication:

```
  (\forall int i; (i >= 0 && i < array.length-1) ==> (array[i] < array[i+1]))
```

With the newer syntax for `\forall`, I believe you could also write:

```
  (\forall int i; (i >= 0 && i < array.length-1) ; (array[i] < array[i+1]))
```

where `(i >= 0 && i < array.length-1)` is the range expression.